# How to prevent FactoryBoy from reusing object of a SubFactory?

Tags: django, testing, factory-boy, django-1.11

I have the following factories:

```
class UserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()


class ProProfileFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    class Meta:
        model = ProfessionalProfile


class UserProfileFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
```

When I inject both pro and user profiles they are associated with the same user:

```
def test_should_create_project(pro_profile, user_profile):
    assert user_profile.user != pro_profile.user
```

This test fail.

**How can I make factory boy create a new user for each profile?**

I'm using Django 1.11, pytest 3.2.2, pytest-django 3.1.2, pytest-factoryboy 1.3.1

Answer (score 1):

You're using the auto-generated model fixtures. From the [docs](http://pytest-factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#subfactory)

> Sub-factory attribute points to the model fixture of the sub-factory. Attributes of sub-factories are injected as dependencies to the model fixture and can be overridden via the parametrization.

So the model fixtures `pro_profile` and `user_profile` both use the model fixture `user`. Hence they are the same. I wasn't expecting this behaviour either, so I've tested a few options

### Override the factory (as in docs)

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('user_profile__user',
                         [LazyFixture(lambda user_factory: user_factory())])
def test_should_create_project(professional_profile, user_profile):
    assert user_profile.user != professional_profile.user
```

### Just use the factory fixtures

```
def test_should_create_project_1(professional_profile_factory, user_profile_factory):
        user_profile = user_profile_factory()
        professional_profile = professional_profile_factory()
        assert user_profile.user != professional_profile.user
```

### Change subfactory during registration

```
register(ProProfileFactory, 'pro_profile_2',
         user=LazyFixture(lambda user_factory: user_factory()))

def test_should_create_project_2(pro_profile_2, user_profile):
    assert user_profile.user != pro_profile_2.user
```

### Using Partial specialization (doesn't work for me)

```
# oddly, this fails for me, partial specialization
register(ProProfileFactory, 'pro_profile_3')
register(UserFactory, 'another_user')

@pytest.fixture
def pro_profile_3__user(another_user):
    return another_user

# This fails
def test_should_create_project_3(pro_profile_3, user_profile):
    assert user_profile.user != pro_profile_3.user
```

I think the easiest way is just to use the factory fixtures `user_profile_factory` and `pro_profile_factory` as they are easiest to reason about.